# AngularJS ng-repeat array with unique $scope variables per item

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am building a food order form and I have a list of options that need to be attached to the individual item index and not to the parent.. As of right now everything works but when i add an option to one product in the array all products have the same value added... ie.. if i choose the vanilla option for latte all drinks in the ng-repeat array will have the vanilla option set to true.. here is what i have..

first here is the html markup of the options view

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
     <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
          <md-card-content class="content">
              <h2 class="md-title">{{ item.name }}</h2>
              <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
              {{flavors(item)}}
              <md-list>
                  <p class="md-subhead">Choose Your Flavor</p>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item ng-repeat="option in options.results" 
                                layout="row">
                      <p> {{ option.name }} </p>
                      <span flex></span>
                      <p> {{ option.price | currency}} </p>
                      <md-checkbox aria-label="option.active"
                                   class="md-accent" 
                                   ng-model="option.active"></md-checkbox>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
           </md-card-content>
           <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                          layout-align="end center">
                          <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                     aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                     ng-click="remove(item)"                               
                                     ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                          </md-button>
            </md-action-bar>
 </md-card>
```

as you can see i have an array of items all with an array of options

here is the factory that retrieves the data from Parse

```
app.factory('ParseData', function($http) {
var ParseFactory = {};

ParseFactory.getItems = function() {

return $http({method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/DrinkMenu/', headers: 
  { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':xxx',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'xxx'}})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};

ParseFactory.getOptions = function() {

return $http({method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Options/', headers: 
  { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'xxx',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'xxx'}})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};

return ParseFactory;

});
```

and lastly the controller

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, ParseData){

  ParseData.getItems().then(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
        }).catch(function() {
        alert('error');
  });

  ParseData.getOptions().then(function(data) {
        $scope.options = data;
        }).catch(function() {
        alert('error');
  });

  });
```

I know this is a little confusing to follow but i tried to explain the issues as best i could.. thanks for taking a look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the flavor model inside the `item`, not a general model as you are doing. The way you are doing the item from the list of `options.results` has the active one, then It will change every selection that uses the `options.results`. Change to:

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="option.active" class="md-accent" 
 ng-model="item.flavor[$index]"></md-checkbox>
```

**OR**

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="option.active" class="md-accent" 
 ng-model="item.flavor[option.name]"></md-checkbox>
```

Comment: ok i just tried that that set all the flavors for that item true not just the one checked...

Comment: @ChrisG updated the answer... I didn't notice that you have multiple flavors.

Comment: ok that works, answer accepted and i never thought about doing it like that... now i do have a question about this way though... all these values will be stored in the $scope item.flavor[$index].. how would i go about getting all those values together to update the price... originally i was thinking of setting the active boolean to true and be able to get those by using a filter..

Comment: @ChrisG just use a filter and update this ones that you have selected for every item. You have the entire flavor inside the $scope item.flavor[$index], including the price :)

Comment: <span ng-repeat="flavor in item.flavor | filter:true">{{flavor.name}}</span>

Comment: but this just shows true not the name... what is the flavor name stored under??? thanks again for taking your time