# AngularJS ng-repeat for an array JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a code in cordova using AngularJS and two JSON array feeds from parse.com. It is basically for a food item with multiple options with variable pricing. I have defined 2 classes called flavors and sizes (doesn't make sense for the type of food, but please bear with me as I'm just testing out). Each food item has a separate set of flavors and sizes defined. I'm having trouble populating the flavors and sizes. Here is the factory that retrieves data from parse:

```
app.factory('ParseData', function($http) {
var ParseFactory = {};

ParseFactory.getItems = function() {

return $http({method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Menu/', headers: 
  { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'X',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'X'}})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};

ParseFactory.getOptions = function() {

return $http({method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Options/', headers: 
  { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'X',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'X'}})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};

return ParseFactory;

});
```

JSON outputs are as follows:

```
{"results":
[{"active":false,
"createdAt":"2015-10-05T20:19:58.264Z",
"desc":"With arugula, smoked almonds \u0026 chipotle vinaigrette",
"img":"https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Watermelon-Quinoa-Jimaca-Salad.jpg",
"name":"Watermelon Quinoa Jicama Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightblue;\"\u003eVE\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: yellow;\"\u003eDF\u003c/span\u003e)",
"objectId":"x1zpkWmvmP",
"price":14,
"updatedAt":"2015-10-09T17:20:50.527Z"},
{"active":false,
"createdAt":"2015-10-05T20:35:01.363Z",
"desc":"Buffalo mozzarella, tomato, marinated artichoke hearts, black olives, pesto \u0026 balsamic drizzle",
"img":"https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Mediterranean-Salad.jpg",
"name":"Mediterranean Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightgreen;\"\u003eV\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e)",
"objectId":"nI5VSpdBUn",
"price":15,
"updatedAt":"2015-10-09T17:20:30.545Z"}]}
```

and

```
{"results":
[{"createdAt":"2015-10-08T19:24:20.527Z",
"flavors":[
{"active":false,"name":"Vanilla","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Almond","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Hazelnut","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Caramel","price":8}],
"objectId":"7lctN9MtLs",
"sizes":[
{"active":false,"name":"Small","price":0},
{"active":false,"name":"Medium","price":5},
{"active":false,"name":"Large","price":10}],
"updatedAt":"2015-10-10T01:14:19.845Z"},
{"createdAt":"2015-10-08T19:25:18.172Z",
"flavors":[
{"active":false,"name":"Strawberry","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Chocolate","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Mint","price":8},
{"active":false,"name":"Cherry","price":8}],
"objectId":"Drj9mdR7or",
"sizes":[
{"active":false,"name":"Small","price":5},
{"active":false,"name":"Medium","price":10},
{"active":false,"name":"Large","price":15}],
"updatedAt":"2015-10-10T01:14:17.632Z"}]}
```

Now, my HTML markup consists of 3 pages, a menu page, an options page and an order page. The menu page populates from the first JSON data and that seems to work perfectly. The options page however is giving me issues. I'm new to retrieving JSON and can't seem to figure this one out. Here is my options.html markup:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
     <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
          <md-card-content class="content">
              <h2 class="md-title"><div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div></h2>
              <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
              <h4>Qty {{ item.qty }}</h4>
              <md-list>
                  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">How Many Would You Like?</h2> 
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item layout="row">
                      <md-slider flex md-primary ng-model="item.qty" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="qty">
                    </md-slider>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
              <md-list>
                  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Choose Your Size</h2>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="size in options.results">
                      <p>{{ size.name }}</p>
                      <span flex></span>
                      <p>{{ size.price | currency }}</p>
                      <md-checkbox aria-label="size set"
                                   class="md-accent"
                                   ng-model="size.active">
                      </md-checkbox>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
              <md-list>
                  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Choose Your Flavor</h2>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results">
                      <p>{{ flavor.name }}</p>
                      <span flex></span>
                      <p>{{ flavor.price | currency }}</p>
                      <md-checkbox aria-label="flavor set"
                                   class="md-accent"
                                   ng-model="flavor.active">
                      </md-checkbox>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
           </md-card-content>
           <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                          layout-align="end center">
                          <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                     aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                     ng-click="remove(item);showRemovedToast();"                               
                                     ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                          </md-button>
            </md-action-bar>
  </md-card>
```

I am able to retrieve data from the first JSON, but not the second. I would really appreciate any help.

EDIT: I'm getting close thanks to Gaurav Sachan. Here's a plunker describing my current issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AmOLsR2rLtco3x9g2q73

The issue now is that the sizes and flavors get repeated for each menu item.

Answer (score 2):

you need to write  instead of  and  instead of

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
 <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
      class="md-card-image" 
      alt="">
      <md-card-content class="content">
          <h2 class="md-title"><div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div></h2>
          <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
          <h4>Qty {{ item.qty }}</h4>
          <md-list>
              <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">How Many Would You Like?</h2> 
              <md-divider></md-divider>
              <md-list-item layout="row">
                  <md-slider flex md-primary ng-model="item.qty" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="qty">
                </md-slider>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
          <md-list>
              <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Choose Your Size</h2>
              <md-divider></md-divider>
              <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="size in options.results.sizes">
                  <p>{{ size.name }}</p>
                  <span flex></span>
                  <p>{{ size.price | currency }}</p>
                  <md-checkbox aria-label="size set"
                               class="md-accent"
                               ng-model="size.active">
                  </md-checkbox>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
          <md-list>
              <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Choose Your Flavor</h2>
              <md-divider></md-divider>
              <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results.flavors">
                  <p>{{ flavor.name }}</p>
                  <span flex></span>
                  <p>{{ flavor.price | currency }}</p>
                  <md-checkbox aria-label="flavor set"
                               class="md-accent"
                               ng-model="flavor.active">
                  </md-checkbox>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
       </md-card-content>
       <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                      layout-align="end center">
                      <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                 aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                 ng-click="remove(item);showRemovedToast();"                               
                                 ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                 <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                      </md-button>
        </md-action-bar>
```

Comment: you need to write  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results.flavors"> instead of <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results."> and <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results.sizes"> instead of <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in options.results">

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes as suggested, but it doesn't seem to be working. Previously, with options.results, I got 2 lines with 2 checkboxes, but blank spaces as the name and price weren't being called. With the changes, I don't get those checkboxes or blank spaces either. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm actually close to figuring this out, thanks to your help! I used flavor in options.results[0].flavors and that seemed to do the trick. Now, I'm experiencing this author's issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931187/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-with-unique-scope-variables-per-item?rq=1

Comment: ok, buddy if u still have any issue, please let me know, i am always ready to help u.

Comment: Thanks bud. The problem is, when I use options.results[0].flavors, only the first set of options get repeated. When I use options.results[1].flavors, only the 2nd set gets repeated. When I use options.results.flavors, nothing gets repeated. That's where I'm stuck at. I can't seem to get it working properly.

Comment: Nope. Here's a plunker showing my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/AmOLsR2rLtco3x9g2q73

Comment: checkout plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/k9TfZL3uxRjDggznDwrE?p=preview  I have added a new span. and it is working fine, becasue we need to iterate all the results then their sizes and flavors.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AmOLsR2rLtco3x9g2q73?p=preview

But a problem still exists. The sizes and flavors repeat for each item. Is there a way to bind the two ng-repeats together, so that they respectively along with the item? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not able to get u , what exactly u want to do, but still please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/LL0KmgrSehf2EEiWCX9s?p=preview here you will get flavours after sizes.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation and thank you so much for your help. In that link, you can see that there are 2 'choose your size' and 'choose your flavor' for each product. I'm trying to get the first sizes and first set of flavors get displayed for the 1st product alone and the 2nd set of sizes and flavors for the second product alone and so on so that it repeats that way. So in that example, the first product should show the first set of sizes and flavors only and the 2nd product should display the 2nd set of sizes and flavors only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to repeat the loop for the flowers so instead of options use item.flower

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I used item.flavor, it's not targeting it. Thanks though.